# 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'split_frame'

Tags: h2o

Unable to Split frame using split_frame(). The dataframe is able to show() but I cannot split it. Please help.

Below is a sample of the code I have used.

```
from h2o.estimators.random_forest import H2ORandomForestEstimator
from h2o.estimators.gbm import H2OGradientBoostingEstimator
from h2o.estimators.deeplearning import H2ODeepLearningEstimator
from h2o.estimators.glm import H2OGeneralizedLinearEstimator
from h2o.estimators.stackedensemble import H2OStackedEnsembleEstimator
from __future__ import print_function

temp = spark.read.option("header","true").option("inferSchema","true").csv("hdfs://bda-ns/user/august_week2.csv")

train,test,valid = temp.split_frame(ratios=[.75, .15])
```

Expected: no error. Data split into test and train data frame.
Actual:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2-2.3.0.cloudera2-1.cdh5.13.3.p0.316101/lib/spark2/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py", line 1182, in __getattr__
    "'%s' object has no attribute '%s'" % (self.__class__.__name__, name))
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'split_frame'
>>> train,test,valid = temp.split_frame(ratios=[.75, .15])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2-2.3.0.cloudera2-1.cdh5.13.3.p0.316101/lib/spark2/python/pyspark/context.py", line 234, in signal_handler
```

Comment: there is no such method `split_frame` in `spark`. look at `sample`. Probably it will help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [randomsplit](https://forums.databricks.com/questions/8723/how-can-i-split-a-spark-dataframe-into-n-equal-dat.html) on your spark dataframe.

If you want to use the H2O-3 split_frame method, you would first have to convert your spark frame to an h2o frame. In which case you could use `hc.as_h2o_frame(spark_df)` where `hc` is your h2o_context (note: you would also need to create the `h2o_context` for this to work).